# Using a variable for map.setcenter in mapbox gl js

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to set the center of my map using coordinates passed into the page via the url. I can retrieve the coords, but but get this error when I try to use them:

Uncaught Error: `LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: , lat: }, or an array of [, ]

I get the coords like this

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + 
'=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [null, ''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
}
var center =getURLParameter('location');
```

open my map with

```
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidHJveWIiLCJhIjoiY2pkb3F0cmJnMHA0YTJ4cXB3Mjc0Y3g0eCJ9.3Myq7AzC4yxR8hi9Ubchdw';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
        center: [-88.75, 42.15],
        zoom: 8
    });
```

and load my layers and set the center of my map in

```
map.on('load', function() { 

map.setCenter(center);
```

my url looks like this:
*http://mywebsite.com/Map.html?location=-84.83762741088867,43.179770125276974&name=otherdata*

I can get the name value and use it to specify my map layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Your method getURLParameter("location") returns latitude,longitude values as string `"-84.83762741088867,43.179770125276974"`

**Step 2:**

Store returned values in a variable

*//It will return string*

```
var center = getURLParameter("location");
```

*//It will return an array ["latitude","longitude"]*

```
var latLng = center.split(",");
```

*//convert the first element of the array to float num*

```
var lat = parseFloat(latLng[0]);
```

*//convert the second element of the array to float num*

```
var lng = parseFloat(latLng[1]);
```

**Step 3:**

Pass converted latitude and longitude values directly to Mapbox GL to center your map.

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZmFyaGF0YWJiYXMiLCJhIjoiY2plODE2NGgxMDRhdjMzcGV6a3QxaGE4OSJ9.O7Gu6jLiZe2y_gPK6AZJyA';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet location
    center: [lng, lat], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
```

or use MapboxGL flyTo method

```
map.flyTo({center:[lng, lat]});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your getURLParameter function is returning a String like "-84.83762741088867,43.179770125276974", but [map.setCenter](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setcenter) needs a [LngLatLike](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglatlike) ie. something like this.

```
var v1 = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-122.420679, 37.772537);
var v2 = [-122.420679, 37.772537];
```

You can use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to get an array assuming your location param is expecting lng,lat. If lat,lng then you'll need to swap the order before passing the array to setCenter.